# How to mount a react app on HTML button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to mount a react application when a button outside of the application is clicked i.e a normal html button.

Here is how I have my index.html set-up:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<button id="button-root">Live chat</button>
<script src="/dist/rafiki.js"></script>
```

I tried using React Portals but all that does is inject a new node into the DOM. What I am trying to achieve is to capture a click on the `#button-root` which toggles the application state to mount the application.

```
const buttonRoot = document.getElementByID('button-root')
    class Main extends React.Component{
       contructor(props){
       this.state = {visible: false}
      }
    
    render(){
      return(
       {this.state.visible && <App />}
    )
   }   
 }
```

this.state.visible should be controlled by clicking the `#button-root`

Comment: Call `ReactDOM.render()` on click of the button?

Comment: Can you support your comment with code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you need to trigger `ReactDOM.render()` when a button is clicked.

Your code might look something like:

```js
document.getElementById('button-root').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
});

const App = () => (
  <p>Mounted!</p>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<button id="button-root">Live chat</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
buttonRoot.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('app'))
})
```

Comment: Tried and it still isn't working. Here is what I have:

`document.getElementById('button-root').addEventListener('click', function() {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
});`

My aim is to toggle the application state when the button is clicked.

Comment: Nothing. No errors. I guess it's because visibility is controlled by my application state.

Comment: Then the app should be rendered but not visible.
Could you please provide some codepen or jsfiddler link?
Also you could try to render smth bigger to see where it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ReactDOM.render()` you can mount a React Component.

You can unmount the same with: `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(appRoot);`

If you need to change state inside the App only once (when it is mounted, then passing it as a prop would suffice:

```js
const appRoot = document.getElementById("app");
const buttonRoot = document.getElementById("button");
const buttonUnmount = document.getElementById("unmount");
const buttonToggle = document.getElementById("toggleVisible");

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: props.visible,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>React Event</p>
        { this.state.visible && <p>Element within App</p> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

buttonRoot.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App visible={true} />, appRoot);
});

buttonUnmount.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(appRoot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button which mounts React</button>
<button id="unmount">Button which removes React App</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you need this multiple times, unmounting and remounting for this purpose might be too costly. You can use a `[CustomEvent][1]` to listen for changes.

```
const event = new CustomEvent("data", { detail: { visible: visibility }});
buttonToggle.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Code:

```js
const appRoot = document.getElementById("app");
const buttonRoot = document.getElementById("button");
const buttonToggle = document.getElementById("toggleVisible");

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    buttonToggle.addEventListener("data", this.listenForEvent);
  }
  listenForEvent = (event) => {
    const data = event.detail;
    this.setState({
      visible: data.visible,
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    buttonToggle.removeEventListener("data", this.listenForEvent);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>React Event</p>
        { this.state.visible && <p>Element within App</p> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

buttonRoot.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, appRoot);
});

let visibility = false;
buttonToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  visibility = !visibility;
  const event = new CustomEvent("data", { detail: { visible: visibility }});
  buttonToggle.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button which mounts React</button>
<button id="toggleVisible">Toggle Visibility within app</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that and it still doens't work the way I expect. My aim is to toggle the application state when the button is clicked. This is to have the button mount and unmount the App when clicked.

Comment: Isn't there a way to control the application state with the button.

Comment: @DaveKalu You want to communicate with the react app from outside?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, to control the state

Comment: Thank you very much.
I typed your solution into a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9z66oxv8p4. The button to mount the app works, however the button to toggle doesn't

Comment: @DaveKalu You have to `mount` the app first and then try toggling. (or leave the app mounted instead of mounting it on click)